# Bicentennial Man or The Positronic Man?

Tags: isaac-asimov, bicentennial-man

I recently learned that the Robin Williams movie Bicentennial Man is based on the novella by Asimov.  In researching this novella I learned that it was later expanded into the novel The Positronic Man.

This leads to my question.  If I read The Positronic Man, will I be missing anything in the novella? Would I be better served by reading the novella and then the book?

Comment: I can't answer directly, but you might want to read the review on Jenkins' Guide: http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book503.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I read The Positronic Man, will I be missing anything in the novella?

Not really. The Positronic Man is an expanded version of Asimov's novella written in conjunction with Robert Silverberg. However the writing style *is* different between the two versions. I would personally read the novella first, ideally while reading the rest of Asimov's Robot short fiction.